# How can i get Express routes to render specific pages

Tags: javascript, express

I am building a blog app with the MEAN stack, i have some routes which query the database for posts then render them using pug.js template engine. the routes look like

```
router.get('/:name', function(req, res) {
    //logic querying mongodb using name as 
    //req.params.id to search for a specific author of the posts and rendering
})
```

This works but when I want to render for example my contact page using router.get'/contact', function etc...

It tries to query for contact rather than rendering the contact.pug file, what can i do to get those pages rendering?

Comment: it's difficult to see exactly what you're doing without seeing your entire routing

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you add routes is important. Express will process the rules in the same order you add them. So the simplest solution would be to put your static routes (like /contact) before the catch-all parametric one for the blog posts.

I.e. make sure the order looks like this:

```
router.get('/contact', ...);
router.get('/:name', ...);
```

Comment: router.get('/:id', ...);

Comment: You can either handle that manually in the `/:name` route (by either checking if `req.params.name` is an ID or just trying to find it in the db twice). Another way is to use a regular expression to define your `/:id` route, [see the docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.METHOD).

Comment: I also have a route which catches authors say /Gorgon but it says it cannot Get Gorgon  when i use regex  '/[A-Z][a-f]+'